# Nuxt2: How to update the element in a current chunk and previous loaded chunks?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, chunks

I have a list of product-cards divided into chunks by 10 items. Each time the user reaches the bottom of the page, the next chunk is loaded without reloading the page. Each product-card has its like-button.

When the user gets another chunk, some product-cards may be loaded again. Or even within the same chunk cards of the same product can be loaded.

The issue is that if the user clicks the like-button, the product gets its +1 like but only in regard of this product-card and the next chunks to be loaded in the future. Can I have all cards of the same product updated regardless of their position on the page? And if I can, how much would this behavior affect performance? Theoretically, users can load hundreds or even thousands of products on a single page.

I have read the documentation on the reactivity in Vue. And it works anywhere on the website as it is expected to. But it does not work with these chunks...

Here are some *simplified* snippets:

*Page with chunks*

```js
<template>
<div
    v-for="(chunk, i) in products"
    :key="i"
    class="chunk"
>
    <div
        v-for="(product) in chunk"
        :key="product.id"
    >
        <ProductCard
            :id="product.id"
            :name="product.name"
            :price="product.price"
            :images="product.images"
            :liked="product.liked"
            :product="product"
        />
    </div>
</div>
</template>

<script>
import { mapState } from 'vuex';

import ProductCard from '@/components/products/ProductCard';

export default {
    components: {
        ProductCard
    }
}
</script>
```

*ProductCard*

```js
<template>
<div>
    <div class="image">
        <ProductImage
            :id="id"
            :images="images"
            :product="product"
        />
    </div>

    <div class="info">
        <h2>{{ name }}</h2>

        <LikeButton
            :liked="isLiked"
            @like="onLike"
            @unlike="onUnlike"
        />

        <PriceButton
            :price-value="currentPrice"
            @click="purchase"
        />
    </div>
</div>
</template>

<script>
import { mapState, mapActions } from 'vuex';

import { likes } from '@/mixins/likes';

import ProductImage from '@/components/products/ProductImage';
import LikeButton from '@/components/common/ui/LikeButton';
import PriceButton from '@/components/common/ui/PriceButton';

export default {
    components: {
        ProductImage,
        LikeButton,
        PriceButton
    },

    mixins: [
        likes
    ],

    props: {
        id: {
            type: Number,
            required: true
        },
        name: {
            type: String,
            default: '',
            required: true
        },
        price: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        images: {
            type: Array,
            default: () => []
        },
        liked: Boolean,
        product: {
            type: Object,
            default: () => ({})
        }
    },

    data() {
        return {
            isLiked: this.liked
        };
    },

    computed: {
        ...mapState('auth', [
            'loggedIn'
        ]),

        currentPrice() {
            // some code here
        }
    },

    methods: {
        purchase() {
            // some code here
        },

        onLike() {
            if (this.loggedIn) {
                if (!this.isLiked) {
                    this.isLiked = true;
                    try {
                        this.like(this.id);
                    } catch (e) {
                        // some code here
                        this.isLiked = false;
                    }
                } else {
                    // some code here
                }
            } else {
                // some code here
            }
        }
    }
};
</script>
```